# Error using .RemoveAt to delete a DataTable row in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm working on a program and don't know how to fix this problem i'm having now.

When i run this code:

```
int maxRows = AfdelingDT.Rows.Count;
maxRows -= 1;
for(int i = 0;i <= maxRows; i++)
{
   if (Convert.ToInt16(AfdelingDT.Rows[i][0]) == Convert.ToInt16(removeRowTB.Text))
   {
      AfdelingDT.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
   }
}
```

I'm having a error that the row doesn't exist if I try to delete a row in the middle of the `DataTable`.

If I run the code for the last row of the table I have no problem at all.

Comment: i think you may need `RemoveAt(i--)` (maybe ++ cant remember, not at a computer with visual studio which is why I've not wrote as answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you remove a row inside a loop, it renumbers all the rows after that point, causing breakage.

Change your code to loop from the end to the beginning:

```
int maxRows = AfdelingDT.Rows.Count;
maxRows -= 1;
for(int i = maxRows;i >= 0; i--)
{
   if (Convert.ToInt16(AfdelingDT.Rows[i][0]) == Convert.ToInt16(removeRowTB.Text))
   {
      AfdelingDT.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
   }
}
```

Comment: really thank you for your answer but i have to say i didn't work.
you still made me clear what my problem is and if i found the answer i will post it if nobody else posted it first.

thx

Comment: oke i should be sow a seamed of my self. i did what you sad (code above) and started at maxRows the only think i didn't see or remembered to do was to change the i++ to i-- what would make the for loop run for 1 round but not how i needed it. sow really thx your answer helped me allot.